# Implementing thread-safe arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, insert, synchronize

I want to implement a array-liked data structure allowing multiple threads to modify/insert items simultaneously. How can I obtain it in regard to performance? I implemented a wrapper class around std::vector and I used critical sections for synchronizing threads. Please have a look at my code below. Each time a thread want to work on the internal data, it may have to wait for other threads. Hence, I think its performance is NOT good. :( Is there any idea?

```
class parallelArray{
private:
    std::vector<int> data;
    zLock dataLock; // my predefined class for synchronizing
public:
    void insert(int val){
         dataLock.lock();
         data.push_back(val);
         dataLock.unlock();
    }

    void modify(unsigned int index, int newVal){
         dataLock.lock();
         data[index]=newVal; // assuming that the index is valid
         dataLock.unlock();
    }
};
```

Comment: google for "lock free datastructures"

Comment: Have you profiled? How do you know performance is not good? It may be good enough for what you are trying to do - other options may be too complex for what you really need to do!?!

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I don't think there is a lockless *array*-like container

Comment: @anhldbk: What does it mean that "performance is not good"? What are you really trying to achieve? If you only want an *array* of integers, you might skip the whole synchronization and just use atomic integer operations, if you want to use generic types depending on your particular requirements you might need to reconsider the data structure.

Comment: Fyi: this code is not exception-safe, for example you could deadlock when that index is NOT valid. You should use some scoped lock system.

Comment: @KillianDS: If the index is not valid (I assume that you are referring to `modify`) it will not deadlock, but rather cause undefined behavior, which is much worse, but non of the operations will throw an exception in the general case (the only operation that can actually throw is the `push_back` if it fails to allocate the new block of memory). Still the advice is more than sound: *always use RAII to hold resources, and a lock is a resource*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: It all depends on what he actually wants to do, what is hard to infer from the example code. An atomic exchange per member might already be ok to him. His insert doing a push_back might be an indication of that a lockless queue could work too. But unless he gives details about the usecase, we can at best make him look and judge himself.

Comment: @Nim: The code is a simplified version of what I'm doing. It must be SCALABLE. Serge Dundich gave me some clues to solve my problem (see below). Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use some fast [reader-writer lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writer_lock). You perform shared locking for read-only access and exclusive locking for writable access - this way read-only access is performed simultaneously.

In user-mode Win32 API there are [Slim Reader/Writer (SRW) Locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904937%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) available in Vista and later.

Before Vista you have to implement reader-writer lock functionality yourself that is pretty simple task. You can do it with one critical section, one event and one enum/int value. Though good implementation would require more effort - I would use hand-crafted linked list of local (stack allocated) structures to implement fair waiting queue.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at shared_mutex in the Boost library.  This allows you to have multiple readers, but only one writer

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.shared_mutex